# AWS SageMaker - Upload our own docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker, docker-image

I am new to AWS SageMaker and i am using this technology for building and training the machine learning models. I have now developed a docker image which contains our custom code for tensorflow. I would like to upload this custom docker image to AWS SageMaker and make use of it.

I have searched various links but could not find proper information on how to upload our own custom docker image.

Can you please suggest me the recommended links regarding the process of uploading our own docker image to AWS SageMaker?

Answer (score 2):

In order to work with sagemaker, you have to push your container to `ECR`. The most important thing is that the container must be "adapted" to be complaint to what sagemaker requires, but everything is described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/docker-containers.html). In addition if you want to take a look to an example, [here](https://github.com/roccopietrini/TFSagemakerDetection) is mine.. where I use my container with TF Object Detection API in AWS Sagemaker.